# How can I dynamically create elements from a library?

Tags: android

How can I dynamically create elements from a library
There is no problem with dynamically creating Buttons, Textviews, ImageButton's and so on but I have pboblem when the element is in a library

For example, I can't dynamically create a carouselview ([Link](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview))
I can have it in xml file and set attributes without any problem
But I need to dynamically create it in the code and then use it

Code:

```
CarouselView carouselView1;
carouselView1 = new CarouselView(getApplicationContext());
```

When I try to set attributes, it gives Error as carouselView1 is null

Comment: How you are setting the attributes ?

Comment: did you try `carouselView1 = new CarouselView(getApplicationContext(),null);`

Comment: @Swayangjit, for example, carouselView1.setPageCount(3);

Comment: Could you please show more code related to the view?

Comment: @ Ta Quang Tu, ok it seems to work without any problem now, what does this null do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer come from my comment above. You should try:

> `CarouselView carouselView1 = new CarouselView(getApplicationContext(), null);`.

As you know. We have 3 popular constructors for view construction, example:

```
public ScrollView(Context context);

public ScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);

public ScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr);
```

The problem may be caused by the author of `CarouselView` has implemented the view fully in the second one but not the first one and the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like following
Don't provide the application context always use Activity context for a view

**Method 1**

```
 CarouselView carouselView1 = new CarouselView(this, null);
 carouselView1.setPageCount(3);
```

**Method 2**

Create one xml file layout_caousel.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/carouselView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:pageColor="#00000000"
    app:radius="6dp"
    app:slideInterval="3000"
    app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>
```

Inflate it like following

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
CarouselView carouselView = (CarouselView) vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_caousel, null);
```

Comment: why the application context should not be provided (If I have to utilize the activity instead then I have to provide the activity as an argument to several classes which is not a good practice as you know)

Comment: arent you using this in Activity ?

Comment: The reason for it is if you use getApplicationContext(), it will live as longer as the Whole Application lives. But for a view, it should destroy as soon the Activity finishes, So it is always better to use Activity's Context when defining such type of Views.

Comment: Really?! So what about the problem I mentioned ?

Comment: Can you tell me your use case why you are not writing this in the activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202085/discussion-between-swayangjit-and-androidhv).